# Ref cursor not returning column names from StoredProcedure?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a Oracle stored procedure which returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. I want to return custom Parameters which is declared inside the stored Procedure. Now, when i call it inside my application(C#), it doesn't show me the column names, instead it gives me names as `:B1`,`:B2`.. etc. How can I achieve this.

ORACLE EG:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyStoredProcedure
(
    OUTPUT_DATA  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
P_NAME VARCHAR2;
P_AGE  VARCHAR2;
P_DOB  VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
     SELECT NAME INTO P_NAME FROM TABLE1;
     SELECT AGE INTO P_AGE FROM TABLE2;
     SELECT DOB INTO P_DOB FROM TABLE3;
OPEN OUTPUT_DATA FOR
    SELECT P_NAME,P_AGE,P_DOB FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Now, when I execute the above code I get the column names as `:B1`,`:B2`,`:B3.` How can i get the column names as `P_NAME`,`P_AGE`,`P_DOB` or some other `alias` names? Is it possilbe? (The same `SELECT QUERY` if you create in `MSSQL` you will get the Parameter names as Column names)

---

I already tried

```
SELECT P_NAME as Name,P_AGE as Age,P_DOB as DOB FROM DUAL;
```

But then also i'm getting the same old result

---

> THE QUERY WITH ALIAS NAME WAS NOT SAVED WHEN I TRIED.

Comment: Can you put up ur c# code to fetch?

Comment: Oracle itself is giving me the column names as :B1,:B2 etc when i run it in my SqlNavigator

Comment: That might be the default behaviour for refcursors in tht tool. You can try sqlplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OPEN OUTPUT_DATA FOR
    SELECT P_NAME as name ,P_AGE as age,P_DOB as dob FROM DUAL;
```

You can test it via sqlplus like this.

```
VARIABLE MYCUR refcursor;
EXEC URPROC (:MYCUR);

print MYCUR;
```

You miss the alias if you choose values in query instead of column names.

Comment: i had not saved it after i put the alias. May be because of it the Column Names were not appearing.